# jQuery navigation bar not working in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my mobile application, I use navigation bar. and i use beta version 1.

```
<div data-role="navbar" id="navibar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="searchNav1">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="shoppingNav1">Shopping</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $('#shoppingNav1').live("click",function() 
{
    alert("in");
    shopping();
    $.mobile.changePage("#shoppingListPage","pop", false, false);
    alert("");
});
```

when i click this it's change the page in my desktop browser but not in actual device

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an object instead of page ID:

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#shoppingListPage"),"pop", false, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

'click' binding doesnt work on phone because iphone generate touch events. us 'tap' instead of "click"